# Eclipse, wrong file encoding when exporting project to jar (not UTF-8) (Ã²)

Tags: eclipse, encoding, utf-8, jar, export

I use Eclipse JEE 2019-12. My Java project has the Text file Encoding set to UTF-8. 
When I export the project to a jar (actually: Export - Deployable plug-ins and fragments) the Strings inside the .class files have wrong characters. For example:
`ò -> Ã²` 
Note: the .class of the project build folder have correct encoding, but .class in the Jar exported have the wrong encoding.
Has someone found a solution to this issue?

Comment: Note: [tag:tycho] with [tag:maven] is the only supported way to build plug-ins these days. There is an option in the Export to use the class files from the project rather than compiling again. Does the Workspace have UTF-8 as the default (Preferences > General > Workspace > Text file encoding)?

Comment: Yes Greg, my workspace had already the UTF-8 setting as default.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:
in the file `<eclipse-home>/eclipse.ini` I inserted the row:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

(at the end of the file or however after the line: `-vmargs`)

Comment: Thank you solution.. I've explored numerous solutions, including utilizing chcp 65001 and incorporating -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 within the Java command, among other attempts. However, ultimately, it was the adjustment of the eclipse.ini configuration that resolved my issue